# Executing code while in background audio mode

Tags: iphone, ios, audio-streaming, background-process

I'm developing app for streaming audio. App have UIBackground mode set to "App plays audio" and this is working like a charm.
However I want to update song information (and display it on lock screen), that info is downloaded json from server.
So I need to execute this code periodically when app is in background. I tried to use NSTimer, detachNewSelector from NSThread and then use NSTimer but it didn't help.

I'm aware that app can't execute code while in background, apart from 10-15 minutes background tasks, but is this true also for apps with Background Modes turned on?
How can I achieve my goal in other way?

Comment: if you want to show song's info while playing in background , you may use MPMovieController for info.

Comment: I know this. The main problem here is: how to download json with song information when app is running in background?

Comment: Have you tried to execute the code the retrieve the JSON? I've create two app wich do this and it's all working.

Comment: While testing the problem in new-test project I forgot to add 

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]      setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];`
It is working now.

@rckoenes did you have any problems with submitting that two apps to the App Store?
Isn't it infringe rules that app should not execute code in background?

Comment: No problem what so ever, since both are Radio Streaming app I already donig some network calls. But even Last.FM app does this, so I do not see any problem with call some JSON webservice.